# Assigning array in multi line texbox winforms

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I am assigning an array in multiline text windows form applications.

when i debug i see like this:

[Assigned Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcIVc.png)

But when it displays i see like this...It is not strings per one line

```
    Part No: 11031=============
    LLDPE Sheet - 2200mm x 1400mm x 0.05mm
    (Code: PES2) Packing: 100 pcs per pack
```

But i need like this:

```
    Part No: 109858

    =============
    Stretch Film (M/R) With Carton Box - 23um x 500mm x 1323m, 15kg

    (Code: SFM3)

    Packing: 46 rolls per Pallet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string.Join()` method, it will gives a string with each array item is separated with a newLine so you will get the required output.The code will be like this:

```
txtRecNo.Text=string.Join("\r\n", stringArr.ToArray());
```

Or

```
 txtRecNo.Text=string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, stringArr.ToArray());
```

Note : The names i chosen from the image you attached with the question.

Comment: Short and Sweet. Nice one (Y) + 1

Comment: It looks like this : Part No: 109858
=============
Stretch Film (M/R) With Carton Box - 23um x 500mm x 1323m, 15kg
 (Code: SFM3)
Packing: 46 rolls per Pallet

Part No: 110313
=============
LLDPE Sheet - 2200mm x 1400mm x 0.05mm
(Code: PES2)
Packing: 100 pcs per pack

Part No: 126626
=============
LLDPE Sheet - 2500mm x 1400mm x 0.05mm
(Code: PES2)
Packing: 100 pcs per pack

Comment: see updates: try `System.Environment.NewLine` instead for `"\n"`